# WP REST API and "Only authenticated users can access the REST API"

Tags: wordpress, rest, authentication

I have a WordPress: https://example.com
I need to use WP REST API.

In .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I use theBasic-Auth plugin on my WordPress: https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth

Nevertheless I have:

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_access",
    "message": "Only authenticated users can access the REST API.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

[image]

I tested with http and https.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved!

I changed it to the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The HTTP_AUTHORIZATION rule has to come before the other rules, this is because the L flag exists, the L flag means (last - stop processing rules), because of this it would never come to that rule if it was after the original wordpress rules,

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and fixed it by verifying whether there is any other Password protection plugin. I was using such a plugin named, `Password Protected` and disabled it to generate the authentication token.

Comment: For me as well there was a plugin enabled called `disable-rest-api` makes sense that such a plugin will block access to the API.